# Times Table - Fizzbuzz Type Question in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm brand new to programming and Ruby is my first language.  One exercise I'm working on is to create a multiplication table that does the following:

```
1x1 = 1
1x2 = 2
(etc)
2x1 = 2
2x2 = 4
```

I figured I'd do this by creating a nested while loop:

```
a = 1
b = 1

while a <= 5
    while b <= 5
        puts "#{a} * #{b} = #{a * b}"

        b += 1
    end
    a += 1  
end
```

When I run the script it prints the first set of times table (1x1 - 1x5) then stops.  It doesn't iterate the parent loop.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never reset your `b` to `1`. Look at the second `while` loop:

```
while b <= 5:
    ...
    b += 1
```

At the end of this loop, `b = 6`, and the loop exits. Then `a += 1` is executed, and our outer loop begins. On all the next inner loop iterations, `b = 6` however, and therefore isn't executed. Thus you need:

```
...
end
a += 1
b = 1
```

Comment: It seems so simple now that it's been shown to me.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4):

You state that you're a novice so a `while` loop is ok for now. But when you improve both your programming and Ruby skills you should be able to write more idiomatic code. Something along those lines:

```
puts [*1..5].product([*1..5]).map { |x, y| "#{x} * #{y} = #{x*y}" }.join("\n")
```

Comment: Hi @tokland.  Thanks for the response.  Yes, I'm definitely a novice.  I'm trying to understand your code.  Please tell  me if I'm reading this correctly:

You have an array range from 1-5 which is being multiplied by another array with a range of 1-5.  Then the array values are being mapped into the x & y variables.  Lastly you add a \n to return each line.  Is that a correct interpretation of what you wrote?

Comment: Another question,why do you need the .join("\n") when using 'puts'?

Comment: After doing research, I see that product(array) doesn't multiply as I assumed, but returns all combinations of the array values.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ErikD: Yeah, the name is a bit misleading, it's a cartesian product. And we need to join the lines to build a unique line. we could also write `lines.each { |line| puts line }`. Note that this is style is called "Functional programming", check it out in the wikipedia. Ruby is not a functional language but you can use a lot of its principles thanks to blocks (higher-order functions).

Answer (score 0):

The "bookkeeping error" explained in the accepted answer is an easy one to make. It is one of the reasons the `each` method is generally preferred to a `while` loop:

```
(1..5).each do |a|
  (1..5).each do |b|
    puts "#{a} * #{b} = #{a * b}"
  end
end
```

No bookkeeping!

Answer (score 0):

```
class MultiplicationTable
i=1
j=5
while i <= j
    (1..12).each do |x|
        puts "#{i} * #{x} = #{i*x}"
    end
    i+=1
end
```

end